# Supervisor 3.3 with Ubuntu 16.04 service start failure

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

This morning, I have upgrade my supervisor by using

```
pip install --upgrade supervisor //from 3.2 to 3.3
```

But after that, service status notice it failure start.

```
supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-05-24 12:19:48 CST; 25s ago
Docs: http://supervisord.org
Process: 27369 ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Process: 27366 ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 27366 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 24 12:19:48 709101111291e5cZ systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 24 12:19:48 709101111291e5cZ systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is my worker config:

```
[program:worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:listen --timeout=360 --queue=high,low --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
exitcodes=0,2
user=www
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/www/worker/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Would please someone could help?

Comment: There are better places to ask such questions such as https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fix the problem by edit `/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service`, and best to use command install supervisor `easy_install supervisor`

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisord Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=50s


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The path of supervisord was wrong in default setting, it was /usr/bin. but pip install will put it in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: "pip install --upgrade supervisor" doesn't install it as service. Did you use "sudo apt-get install supervisor"? If so, then it's installed in /usr/bin...

Comment: @vgoklani Actually, I make two way to install it, as the official Ubuntu package is only 3.2, and then I upgrade it by pip install --upgrade.

Answer (score 35):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 using Supervisor 3.2 and am getting the same error when i try to start supervisor with service supervisor start.

I used `apt-get install supervisor` to install supervisor and it put supervisorctl and supervisord in `/usr/bin/`.

And my `supervisor.service` file is pointing at `/usr/bin/`. I'm stuck.

UPDATE
I found the problem, it turns out there was a parsing error in one of my .conf files in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`. Once I fixed that it worked. That error was not at all clear but there is a hint as to how to find it. In there original error output there is a line like

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf  (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`

Run `/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` from the command line and it will give you a more verbose error.

Comment: I also had this problem. I think it's wise to first start supervisor without any config files, then add your config files and see which ones don't work.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue, where I was getting a status=2 as the exit code. There were no further clues as to what could be going wrong.

Turns out that Supervisor won't start if it's log folder doesn't exist. Since this folder was mounted on a tmpfs, after a reboot of the device, it would have been wiped again.

This caused Supervisor to not boot up (known issue: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/121)

As a fix, I added the following lines to my startup script:

```
mkdir /var/log/supervisor
sudo service supervisor restart
```

Now the folder gets created on startup and supervisor starts correctly.

Comment: Installing and enabling supervisor on a clean ubuntu install made me run into the same problem, and this seems to have solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have not idea about how to start the service in Ubuntu, even though it has `/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service` and config right. But when you `service supervisor start` it loaded masked.
I use tip, both `apt install supervisor` and `easy_install supervisor`, then `easy_install -U supervisor`. Now, it has two difference versions of it, 

`/usr/local/bin/supervisord --version  // Version 3.3.3 until 26th,Jan,2018
/usr/bin/supervisord --version        // Version 3.2.0 Ubuntu 16.04`

After that, edit `/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service` and `/etc/init.d/supervisor`, change all the `/usr/bin/supervisord` to `/usr/local/bin/supervisord`

Finally, in bash, reload the service config. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
Now, all the service run the latest version of supervisor.

Maybe, could try this to unmask the service.

```
systemctl unmask supervisor
systemctl enable supervisor
systemctl restart supervisor
```